# Requirement to include reference to support an interface

Tags: c#, interface

Assume that I have a library which defines an interface:

```
namespace LibraryOne
{
   public interface ISomething
   {
       void DoSomething();
   }
}
```

I implement this in a second library

```
namespace LibraryTwo
{
   public class Something : ISomething
   {
       public void DoSomething() { throw new Exception("I don't know how to do anything!"); }
   }
}
```

I then use this class in a third library

```
namespace LibraryThree
{
   public class MyClass
   {
      private Something myThing = new Something();
      public void DoIt() { 
          myThing.DoSomething();
      }
   }
}
```

Visual Studio tells me that `LibraryThree` has to have a reference to `LibraryOne` for this code to work.  Even if I make `ISomething` `internal` and make `LibraryOne` `InternalsVisibleTo` `LibraryTwo`, I still have to have that reference.  **Why?**

If I actually referred to an `ISomething`, I'd understand.  If I expected `Something` to behave like an `ISomething`, I'd understand.  But I just need to treat it as a `Something`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just need to treat it as a `Something`

That's the thing: the moment you implement `ISomething` in `Something`, it becomes an `ISomething` too. The fact that a class implements an interface is integral to that classes nature.

Without this, you would be able to inherit `Something` to create `SomethingElse`, and that `SomethingElse` would not implement `ISomething`. Now consider this example:

```
public class Something : ISomething
{
    public void DoSomething() { ... }
    // Add this method
    public void ProcessSomething(Something other) {
        ISomething byInterface = other; // This is legal
        // Now do something with byInterface
    }
}
```

Your hypothetical code does this:

```
public class SomethingElse : Something {
   ...
}
```

Now pass an instance of `SomethingElse` to `ProcessSomething` to complete the circle: your `SomethingElse` is a `Something` but it is not `ISomething`, breaking the cast that C# expect to work unconditionally.

Comment: Thanks.  That made it much clearer.  Out of curiosity, since I didn't think to test this before, if I referenced another class from `LibraryTwo`, which *didn't* implement `ISomething`, would it still require me to reference `LibraryOne`?  What if it used it internally but never exposed it?

Comment: @Bobson If `LibraryOne` were used internally and never exposed as part of the `LibararyTwo`'s interface (through inheritance, return parameters, or method arguments), you wouldn't need to reference `LibraryOne` in your `LibraryThree` code.

Answer (score 3):

When the CLR executes your application, it loads all the information about the types referenced in your program.

Because `Something` implements `ISomething`, the CLR needs to know about the interface - so the .dll containing this interface has to be accessible to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have a library that calls another library you need both in your top level project. How else do you expect the top project to assemble all the necessary files during build?